# Show that $α - iβ$ is also a root for $y'' + a_1y' + a_2y = 0$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, roots

Please help me with the following problem:

> Consider the equation $y'' + a_1y' + a_2y = 0$, where the constants $a_1, a_2$ are real. Suppose $α + iβ$ is a complex root of the characteristic polynomial, where $α, β$ are real, $β≠0$.
>
> > Show that $α - iβ$ is also a root.

Comment: Is this really related with the differential equation? Isn't that a general fact of second degree equations?

Comment: This is trivial. The characteristic equation is a second degree equations with real coefficients, one it's root is complex, so other is it's conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is of the form
$$ k^2+a_1 k + a_2 = 0. $$
$\alpha+i\beta$ is a root, so
$$ (\alpha+i\beta)^2+a_1 (\alpha+i\beta) + a_2 = 0. $$
There are now two ways to proceed:

1. If you are comfortable taking complex conjugates, you have
   $$ 0 = \overline{(\alpha+i\beta)^2+a_1 (\alpha+i\beta) + a_2} = (\alpha-i\beta)^2+a_1 (\alpha-i\beta) + a_2, $$
   since $\alpha,\beta,a_1,a_2$ are real, and hence $\alpha-i\beta$ is a root.
2. Alternatively, we can take real and imaginary parts:
   $$ 0 = \alpha^2-\beta^2 +a_1\alpha + a_2, \\
   0 = 2\alpha\beta + a_1 \beta $$
   These equations are still both satisfied if we replace $\beta$ by $-\beta$, so $\alpha-i\beta$ is a root.